# how can i create a condition who will display several element from a json file?

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I want to create a condition that will do this :
if into a sentence the "department name " is equal to the department name from the json file , we display the sentence with other element, in link with the department name selected, like  his population ,his department code .

the json file look like this (many longer than this ):

```
[
    {
        "datasetid": "population-francaise-par-departement-2018",
        "recordid": "7b81f8adc3cb71b942540e51d868992a7d588595",
        "fields": {
            "departement": "Orne",
            "code_departement": "61",
            "geom": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -0.7399722943,
                        48.6217032013
                    ],
                    [
                        -0.7388681294,
                        48.622541151
                    ],
                    [
                        -0.4329546858,
                        48.8633021563
                    ],
                    [
                        -0.4305570769,
                        48.8630882975
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geo_point_2d": [
                48.62307419424573,
                0.127896583868712
            ],
            "population": 282516
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                0.127896583868712,
                48.62307419424573
            ]
        },
        "record_timestamp": "2018-06-21T14:36:09.020+02:00"
    },
    {
        "datasetid": "population-francaise-par-departement-2018",
        "recordid": "7b81f8adc3cb71b942540e51d868992a7d588595",
        "fields": {
            "departement": "Blois",
            "code_departement": "28",
            "geom": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -0.7399726385,
                        22.6217542752
                    ],
                    [
                        -0.7388681294,
                        55.622541151
                    ],
                    [
                        -0.4329546858,
                        47.8633021563
                    ],
                    [
                        -0.4305570769,
                        12.8630882975
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geo_point_2d": [
                48.62307419424573,
                0.127896583868712
            ],
            "population": 254654
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                0.127896583868712,
                48.62307419424573
            ]
        },
        "record_timestamp": "2018-06-21T14:36:09.020+02:00"
    }
]
```

i had try  this:

```
<?php

$populationdata = file_get_contents('population-francaise-par-departement-2018.json');

$myfile = json_decode($populationdata, true);

foreach($myfile as $record) { 
$name = "Blois";
$sentence= 'you are in the department call '. $name . ' the population is about '. $thepopulation .' people ' . "the code  departement is: ". $codedepartement;

     if($record['fields']['departement'] === $nom){
         echo $sentence;

     }
}
```

The problem here :
The code display the sentence but the population information an code department  are not the good one how can i select the good one ?

thank you by advance !

I would like something display like this each time in my sentence the department name exist in the json file :

`You are in the department call  "Blois" the population is about "254654" people the code department is: "28";`

Comment: Define this varible before sentence `$thepopulation = $record['fields']['population']` and `$codedepartement = $record['fields']['code_departement']`

Comment: you did not define `$nom` variable also.

Comment: what do you mean about define i put $name ="Blois" this is not good ??

Comment: Check your if condition `if($record['fields']['departement'] === $nom){` here is wrong variable `$nom`.

Comment: oh okey the reason i put this is that in a first time i try something like this  $name=$record['fields']['departement'];
$thepopulation=$record['fields']['population'];
$codedepartement=$record['fields']['code_departement']; and write $name in my condition but he did'nt work

Answer (score 1):

You could try a function like this. It looks for the passed department name in the `departement` field, and then uses the returned index to look up the population and code:

```
function show_population($data, $department) {
    $fields = array_column($data, 'fields');
    $k = array_search($department, array_column($fields, 'departement'));
    if ($k !== false) {
        $sentence = 'you are in the department call '. $department . ' the population is about '. $fields[$k]['population'] .' people ' . "the code  departement is: ". $fields[$k]['code_departement'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        $sentence = 'the department ' . $department . ' has no data available' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $sentence;
}

echo show_population($myfile, 'Blois');
echo show_population($myfile, 'Paris');
```

Output:

```
you are in the department call Blois the population is about 254654 people the code  departement is: 28
the department Paris has no data available
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sPWRF)